# Allow a web application to access a local file

Tags: php, asp.net

If I have a web application that needs to use a file, it presents the user with a standard open file dialog. But instead of uploading the file to server can it modify the file locally in a temporary location, while uploading in the background? That way the user does not have to wait for the upload before they can use my web app.

Comment: You can get the data as base64 in **firefox** with: attachment.files.item(0).getAsDataURL();  Browser specific though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Gazler, there is some sort of solution in firefox. I can't verify this.

However, I have to ask why this is necessary or reasonable. If you are modifying the file locally, then it will not be the same as the file uploading in the background, will it?

Perhaps I need an context for this to be reasonable.

Regardless, there is no real way to do this that I know of.

Comment: Say you the web app edits a photo, you can be uploading the original while the user makes modifications, using their computer not the server. The different modifications can be recorded and then sent to the server, where they are applied to the image once it has uploaded.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd ever go that route, however....

Perhaps a Java/Flash applet would be best suited for this? I'm not sure it's possible with just Javascript.